# MySQL for Visual Studio generate ASP.NET application option missing

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I've been trying to create a Web api for a mobile application. Both the front end of the app and the database have been completed at this point. I have the database hosted on XAMPP and a secondary deployment on an Ubuntu VM.

I've been [following a guide to generate a MySQL ASP.NET MVC project](https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/howto:-using-mysql-for-visual-studio-in-you-first-aspnet-mvc-application-with-ef-6) which appears to make the generation of a web api for my databse very easy.

The requirements for the project are according to the guide:

- Visual Studio 2013 Professional edition or higher.
- MySQL Connector/Net 6.9.x driver available on the MySQL Developer Zone
- MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.2 available on the MySQL Developer Zone
- A MySQL server instance running. It can be use 5.5.x, 5.6.x or 5.7.x

**I meet all these requirements having VS 2017, MySQL Connector/Net 6.9.9, and MySQL for Visual Studio 2.0.5 (I originally had 1.2.2, but updated the newer version as a precaution)**
[image: Proof of installation]

---

At this point in the guide, their mysql toobar simply has a button to generate MySQL MVC projects while mine is just missing.
[image: Guide's MySQL toolbar]

[image: My MySQL toolbar]

---

Additionally I have noticed that I am missing the 'MySQL Website Configuration Tool' button in my solution explorer.

[image: Guide]

Comment: Does it change if you select a connection and not *Data Connections* in the list view like they do?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen No, that picture is just to highlight the lack of the button.